# eslint error 'foo is defined but never use (no-unused-vars)' in for of loop

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

in a `for of` loop written as below

```
 for (let child of main.childNodes) {
      if (child.textContent === w.toUpperCase()) {
        const classes = child.classList;
        classes.toggle('show');
        break;
      }
}
```

but in vscode it gives eslint error,

`child` is defined but never use (no-unused-vars)

check screenshot
[image: eslint error]

what could be the issue here

vscode v: 1.74.2

#### .eslintrc

```
module.exports = {
  extends: ['eslint:recommended'],
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  rules: {},
};
```

from package.json

```json
    "eslint": "^8.30.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
```

what could be the issue and how to eliminitae this error

Comment: The `main` variable has a problem (it's underlined in red). If you fix that one first, probably ESLint will start recognizing `child` as well and will no longer complain.

Comment: it is saying ts lint error `main` is probably null while this is vanilla js file while  main =doument.querySelector ('main')

Comment: `const main= document.querySelector ('.main')`